# Why do I have to divide the width of my raw image data by 3?

Tags: c++, biometrics

So I'm almost at the finish line I feel. I'm working on a fingerprint reader project that I need for work. Needs to be done by Mid January so I need this to work :)

I've been jumping around all over the internet to find a library that already takes the image from my reader and I was referred to Griaule. Long Story Short, after much frustration I concluded that Griaule is outdated, too complex for what it's supposed to do, too expensive and overall way too hard to get to work properly.

So I decided to take another approach where I use the examples provided by Microsoft and then use another library I got to take care of the processing once I got the image.

I am now at the point where I can scan a fingerprint and then make a BMP file. But the file's aspect ratio is weird. It looks very tall and squished together even though (if memory serves) the scanner should have a higher resolution.

The console writes out that the image should be `256 x 360` but I have to divide that width by 3 to make the image work. So it comes out as `85x360` which doesn't look quite right.

So here is the function that saves the image as BMP:

```
bool SaveBMP(BYTE* buffer, int width, int height, long paddedsize, LPCTSTR bmpfile) {
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER info;
    memset(&bmfh, 0, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    bmfh.bfType = 0x4d42; // Don't question it. Magic Word (B and M). It's necessary. Seriously.
    bmfh.bfReserved1 = 0;
    bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;
    bmfh.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)+paddedsize;
    bmfh.bfOffBits = 0x36;
    info.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    info.biWidth = width;
    info.biHeight = height;
    info.biPlanes = 1;

    info.biBitCount = 24;
    info.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    info.biSizeImage = 0;
    info.biXPelsPerMeter = 0x0ec4;
    info.biYPelsPerMeter = 0x0ec4;
    info.biClrUsed = 0;

    info.biClrImportant = 0;

    HANDLE file = CreateFile(bmpfile, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    unsigned long bwritten;
    if (WriteFile(file, &bmfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &bwritten, NULL) == false) {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return false;
    }

    if (WriteFile(file, &info, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &bwritten, NULL) == false) {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return false;
    }

    if (WriteFile(file, buffer, paddedsize, &bwritten, NULL) == false) {
        CloseHandle(file);
        return false;
    }

    CloseHandle(file);
    return true;
}
```

The Code used to Capture the Fingerprint:

```
HRESULT CaptureSample()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    WINBIO_SESSION_HANDLE sessionHandle = NULL;
    WINBIO_UNIT_ID unitId = 0;
    WINBIO_REJECT_DETAIL rejectDetail = 0;
    PWINBIO_BIR sample = NULL;
    SIZE_T sampleSize = 0;

    // Connect to the system pool. 
    hr = WinBioOpenSession(
        WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT,    // Service provider
        WINBIO_POOL_SYSTEM,         // Pool type
        WINBIO_FLAG_RAW,            // Access: Capture raw data
        NULL,                       // Array of biometric unit IDs
        0,                          // Count of biometric unit IDs
        WINBIO_DB_DEFAULT,          // Default database
        &sessionHandle              // [out] Session handle
        );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf_s(L"\n WinBioOpenSession failed. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
        goto e_Exit;
    }

    // Capture a biometric sample.
    wprintf_s(L"\n Calling WinBioCaptureSample - Swipe sensor...\n");
    hr = WinBioCaptureSample(
        sessionHandle,
        WINBIO_NO_PURPOSE_AVAILABLE,
        WINBIO_DATA_FLAG_RAW,
        &unitId,
        &sample,
        &sampleSize,
        &rejectDetail
        );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        if (hr == WINBIO_E_BAD_CAPTURE)
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\n Bad capture; reason: %d\n", rejectDetail);
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf_s(L"\n WinBioCaptureSample failed. hr = 0x%x\n", hr);
        }
        goto e_Exit;
    }

    wprintf_s(L"\n Swipe processed - Unit ID: %d\n", unitId);
    wprintf_s(L"\n Captured %d bytes.\n", sampleSize);

    // Art "Messiah" Baker at Microsoft

    PWINBIO_BIR_HEADER BirHeader = (PWINBIO_BIR_HEADER)(((PBYTE)sample) + sample->HeaderBlock.Offset);
    PWINBIO_BDB_ANSI_381_HEADER AnsiBdbHeader = (PWINBIO_BDB_ANSI_381_HEADER)(((PBYTE)sample) + sample->StandardDataBlock.Offset);
    PWINBIO_BDB_ANSI_381_RECORD AnsiBdbRecord = (PWINBIO_BDB_ANSI_381_RECORD)(((PBYTE)AnsiBdbHeader) + sizeof(WINBIO_BDB_ANSI_381_HEADER));
    PBYTE firstPixel = (PBYTE)((PBYTE)AnsiBdbRecord) + sizeof(WINBIO_BDB_ANSI_381_RECORD);
    int width = AnsiBdbRecord->HorizontalLineLength;
    int height = AnsiBdbRecord->VerticalLineLength;

    wprintf_s(L"\n ID: %d\n", AnsiBdbHeader->ProductId.Owner);
    wprintf_s(L"\n Width: %d\n", AnsiBdbRecord->HorizontalLineLength);
    wprintf_s(L"\n Height: %d\n", AnsiBdbRecord->VerticalLineLength);
    wprintf_s(L"\n Horizontal Img. Res.: %d\n", AnsiBdbHeader->HorizontalImageResolution);
    wprintf_s(L"\n Horizontal Scan Img. Res.: %d\n", AnsiBdbHeader->HorizontalScanResolution);
    wprintf_s(L"\n Vertical Img. Res.: %d\n", AnsiBdbHeader->VerticalImageResolution);
    wprintf_s(L"\n Vertical Scan Img. Res.: %d\n", AnsiBdbHeader->VerticalScanResolution);
    wprintf_s(L"\n First Pixel: %d\n", firstPixel);
    wprintf_s(L"\n Element Count: %d\n", AnsiBdbHeader->ElementCount);

    bool b = SaveBMP(firstPixel, width, height, 0, L"C:\\Users\\smf\\Desktop\\fingerprint.bmp");
    wprintf_s(L"\n Success: %d\n", b);

e_Exit:
    if (sample != NULL)
    {
        WinBioFree(sample);
        sample = NULL;
    }

    if (sessionHandle != NULL)
    {
        WinBioCloseSession(sessionHandle);
        sessionHandle = NULL;
    }

    wprintf_s(L"\n Press any key to exit...");
    _getch();

    return hr;
}
```

What I don't quite understand (as I am new to C++ in general but versed in higher level languages) is that in order for this function to work, I have to divide whatever width I pass to the function by 3. If I don't do this, the image will come out not working.

What is the reason behind this, and if possible, how would I make the picture retain it's original width?

Comment: Is it possible that every pixel is 24bit (i.e. 3 bytes) wide (8bit R, 8bit for G and 8bit for B)?

Comment: It seems, that you expect 24 bits per pixel in one place of you code and 8 bits per pixel in another place (i.e. you don't need colours, you need only brightness). Since ratio of these values is three, you have the same ratio of widths.

Comment: @Ilya Where do you see the 8 bits per pixel part?

Comment: @Vipar, I expect the scanner returns not very good image (i.e. not 24 bits, but 8 bits per pixel, since it is enough). But I am not sure. Also here we can see only implementation of BMP saving. But where is the code which obtains the data from the scanner?

Comment: How do you determine `paddedsize`? BMP images don't have padding at the end of an image. They *do* have padding at the end of each line. Perhaps you are confusing these?

Comment: I have added the code that captures the fingerprint. It should be noted that this code is put together mostly by looking at Microsoft pages and a few Stackoverflow examples which means I might not be 100 % sure of what is happening. Again, new to C++ so sorry for the inconvenience there.

Comment: Your fingerprint is in grey scale. `AnsiBdbHeader->PixelDepth` will give you the number of bits per pixel, which is 8 in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the image returned by WinBioCaptureSample is a grayscale bitmap, i.e. it uses 8 bits per pixel.
Your implementation of SaveBitmap writes a 24bit RGB bitmap. So it needs 3 times the number of bytes as the original fingerprint bitmap (or - as you already found out - it will shrink the image by factor 3).

So, in order to solve the problem, you need to triple each byte at some point. Either within SaveBitmap or before passing the data to it.

Comment: Triple each byte though. Does that mean taking a byte and just multiply it up by 3? Or the amount of bytes per byte with three so that 9 bytes would become 9 * 3 bytes more?

Comment: @Vipar Basically, you need to convert the image, so you need to create the 24-bit version and fill it, with R = G = B = 8-bit value.

Comment: I have the same problem... Did you get this to work? If you (width / 3) it generates shrinked image. Please upload your code